# How to build a RSS Listnener

Tags: server, rss

I am currently building a small iOS app that will send notifications to its users when some new content is available in a set of pre-selected websites.

For that purpose, in a separate environment, I need to listen to a set of RSS feed, detect new items,and send a simple web request to my iCloud server whenever a new item is created (I do not need to store or aggregate the feed).

I have been struggling to find the right way to build this kind of RSS listener. I was expecting to find dozen of tools, but so fare I could only find  some aggregators. My best guess so fare would be to use a Windows Server and set-it up from scratch myself.

Does anybody has any suggestion on how to proceed or any recommended tool / technology?

Thanks!

Comment: Being as your question is open-ended, I'll not try to answer, but will note that this seems like a fine thing to write a node.js app for. It could fire up, via cron, every hour or whatever, and then poll the RSS feeds, compare to its saved list of entries in that feed, and send whatever message you need to send where ever you need to send it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Derrell!